# Increased memory_limit and not reflecting

Tags: php, shell, apache2, debian

Wrote info.php file with  phpinfo function And their i found php.ini file path in `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`. Opened php.ini file and changed memory_limit from 256M  to 512M.Using shell command called 'service apache2 restart' apache was restarted.

And again executed info.php. But it is showing the same 256M. memory_limit not updated with 512 M. Working on Apache/2.2.16 (Debian).

Tried a lot and lot. Restarted, reloaded apache2 in hundreds of times. But no change.

Please can anyone can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check the path of php.ini which ini file is loaded..

Comment: I agree with @Pramod. This file path is shown in the column "Loaded Configuration File"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the path of php.ini from where the file is loaded. There are many php.ini files so make sure you change in the correct php.ini file.

Comment: Yes, "Loaded Configuration File" /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini, when i executed info.php, So, Path is correct. I have edited the file which is in /etc/php5/apache2/. But no change.

Comment: Please could any one have idea where i have missed as its quite urgent.

Comment: @user2138582 restart all the services

Comment: To restart apache->service apache2 restart and don't know the shell command to restart all the services?  Thanks Pramod for your fast help.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. Actually setting were written in "Additional .ini files parsed" section in /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/a.ini. Again i have gone through the php info file. I changed there. Then it worked for me.

Comment: @user2138582 your welcome..if it helps you, you can upvote or accept this as an answer :)